# remove dictionaries from list based on key value from nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filter

I have the following list of dictionary:

```
item = {
    "relationship": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "id": "",
            "type": "",
            "relationship": {
                "id": "3006:33",
                "fkey_logical_column_id": "2006:41",
                "pkey_logical_column_id": "2006:51",
                "fkey_column_id": "3003:9",
                "fkey_column_name": "\"localhost:1521/orcl\"..\"OT\".\"ORDER_ITEMS\".\"ORDER_ID\"",
                "pkey_column_id": "3003:17",
                "pkey_column_name": "\"localhost:1521/orcl\"..\"OT\".\"ORDERS\".\"ORDER_ID\"",
                "fkey_table_id": "3001:7",
                "pkey_table_id": "3001:14",
                "pkey_physical_table_name": "",
                "pkey_business_table_name": "",
                "type": "",
                "fkey_business_column_name": "\"ofline_online_test\".\"ORDER_ITEMS\".\"ORDER_ID\"",
                "pkey_business_column_name": "\"ofline_online_test\".\"ORDERS\".\"ORDER_ID\"",
                "from_type": "0..1",
                "to_type": "n..n"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "id": "",
            "type": "",
            "relationship": {
                "id": "3006:34",
                "fkey_logical_column_id": "2006:42",
                "pkey_logical_column_id": "2006:70",
                "fkey_column_id": "3003:10",
                "fkey_column_name": "\"localhost:1521/orcl\"..\"OT\".\"ORDER_ITEMS\".\"PRODUCT_ID\"",
                "pkey_column_id": "3003:29",
                "pkey_column_name": "\"localhost:1521/orcl\"..\"OT\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"PRODUCT_ID\"",
                "fkey_table_id": "3001:7",
                "pkey_table_id": "3001:25",
                "pkey_physical_table_name": "",
                "pkey_business_table_name": "",
                "type": "",
                "fkey_business_column_name": "\"ofline_online_test\".\"ORDER_ITEMS\".\"PRODUCT_ID\"",
                "pkey_business_column_name": "\"ofline_online_test\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"PRODUCT_ID\"",
                "from_type": "0..1",
                "to_type": "n..n"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "id": "",
            "type": "",
            "relationship": {
                "id": "3006:35",
                "fkey_logical_column_id": "2006:67",
                "pkey_logical_column_id": "2006:61",
                "fkey_column_id": "3003:26",
                "fkey_column_name": "\"localhost:1521/orcl\"..\"OT\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"CATEGORY_ID\"",
                "pkey_column_id": "3003:22",
                "pkey_column_name": "\"localhost:1521/orcl\"..\"OT\".\"PRODUCT_CATEGORIES\".\"CATEGORY_ID\"",
                "fkey_table_id": "3001:25",
                "pkey_table_id": "3001:21",
                "pkey_physical_table_name": "",
                "pkey_business_table_name": "",
                "type": "",
                "fkey_business_column_name": "\"ofline_online_test\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"CATEGORY_ID\"",
                "pkey_business_column_name": "\"ofline_online_test\".\"PRODUCT_CATEGORIES\".\"CATEGORY_ID\"",
                "from_type": "0..1",
                "to_type": "n..n"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a search id **pkey_table_id = 3001:14 ** which is present in first item of list item["relationship"][0]["relationship"]["pkey_table_id"].
I want to loop through list with key item["relationship"] and if the match is found with **pkey_table_id = 3001:14 ** i want to delete that particular item from list .So my result would be
required output

```
item = {
    "relationship": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "id": "",
            "type": "",
            "relationship": {
                "id": "3006:34",
                "fkey_logical_column_id": "2006:42",
                "pkey_logical_column_id": "2006:70",
                "fkey_column_id": "3003:10",
                "fkey_column_name": "\"localhost:1521/orcl\"..\"OT\".\"ORDER_ITEMS\".\"PRODUCT_ID\"",
                "pkey_column_id": "3003:29",
                "pkey_column_name": "\"localhost:1521/orcl\"..\"OT\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"PRODUCT_ID\"",
                "fkey_table_id": "3001:7",
                "pkey_table_id": "3001:25",
                "pkey_physical_table_name": "",
                "pkey_business_table_name": "",
                "type": "",
                "fkey_business_column_name": "\"ofline_online_test\".\"ORDER_ITEMS\".\"PRODUCT_ID\"",
                "pkey_business_column_name": "\"ofline_online_test\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"PRODUCT_ID\"",
                "from_type": "0..1",
                "to_type": "n..n"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "id": "",
            "type": "",
            "relationship": {
                "id": "3006:35",
                "fkey_logical_column_id": "2006:67",
                "pkey_logical_column_id": "2006:61",
                "fkey_column_id": "3003:26",
                "fkey_column_name": "\"localhost:1521/orcl\"..\"OT\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"CATEGORY_ID\"",
                "pkey_column_id": "3003:22",
                "pkey_column_name": "\"localhost:1521/orcl\"..\"OT\".\"PRODUCT_CATEGORIES\".\"CATEGORY_ID\"",
                "fkey_table_id": "3001:25",
                "pkey_table_id": "3001:21",
                "pkey_physical_table_name": "",
                "pkey_business_table_name": "",
                "type": "",
                "fkey_business_column_name": "\"ofline_online_test\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"CATEGORY_ID\"",
                "pkey_business_column_name": "\"ofline_online_test\".\"PRODUCT_CATEGORIES\".\"CATEGORY_ID\"",
                "from_type": "0..1",
                "to_type": "n..n"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
id_input = 3001:14
item ['relationship'] = list(filter(lambda i: i['pkey_table_id'] != id_input , item['relationship']['relationship']))
```

Comment: Move one `['relationship']` to `i['relationship']['pkey_table_id']`

Comment: Thank you ..my updated code works `item ['relationship'] = list(filter(lambda i: i['relationship']['pkey_table_id'] != id_input , item ['relationship']))
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost right, a bit corrected your code:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3Vddb6owGL7nV3B6gyaGUfAjI9nFMs2yi8XF47lYdGlQymxWWgL1wiz@dk9Fp6KwUeaSxd7063n7PO3bPoFoIWacOauVjwM9ivkUJ0mNCBzWXU2XhfiIsGgu9BvdcCwLurBpbCYkZmTEmHqCcJbMSGS8SBAliagFhAoc16gXTnxPJ65OjpEjI3rDCyS8CcWI@DL0z82eq5G7er2uaetxyfKeSgCH88DVR@nourzvWimOeSGW8wA0suPEzxsViygXfcSW5ThYTx5T23Wco/AUEKw3TfkrmXoUTTmdhwxtgux1UBPmBUWfB7VgIVMGLGU57vVX2I@jGgPKJd@MJ8KFLRte8XhKx8A0x6A/lLWsBt3eAD0Me49/D/vdMSjcxKke2PkKrCiojJbg8OptpUC3WMkJFDYLsdFskaSJ2gQV3Lw9fjJPCJNvrgS@4F7ut7Rb6@ToeEDlDOIsrQRORNUUVuMolZWYh@hjj5Zp5l5rwXcQZpoMZBDLXW/Z@E1W0KxiBXYFK@hYClYArZ/zgqdBv/vvbqjqBvb1@dxgK6Gcnm87gt26TEcolUhlFrXcXKwvtCr4QrtTwRfaKp8Idvt8vpBJ9N3tsHffHzwru4J9dldAWy0PvZLSAtVXf4qFl@EQFVJalUM9S@e0irT1oi01LfNbJHuEiW17tfoP)

```
def process(item):
    id_input = '3001:14'
    item['relationship'] = list(filter(lambda i:
        i['relationship']['pkey_table_id'] != id_input , item['relationship']))

item = {
    "relationship": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "id": "",
            "type": "",
            "relationship": {
                "id": "3006:33",
                "fkey_logical_column_id": "2006:41",
                "pkey_logical_column_id": "2006:51",
                "fkey_column_id": "3003:9",
                "fkey_column_name": "\"localhost:1521/orcl\"..\"OT\".\"ORDER_ITEMS\".\"ORDER_ID\"",
                "pkey_column_id": "3003:17",
                "pkey_column_name": "\"localhost:1521/orcl\"..\"OT\".\"ORDERS\".\"ORDER_ID\"",
                "fkey_table_id": "3001:7",
                "pkey_table_id": "3001:14",
                "pkey_physical_table_name": "",
                "pkey_business_table_name": "",
                "type": "",
                "fkey_business_column_name": "\"ofline_online_test\".\"ORDER_ITEMS\".\"ORDER_ID\"",
                "pkey_business_column_name": "\"ofline_online_test\".\"ORDERS\".\"ORDER_ID\"",
                "from_type": "0..1",
                "to_type": "n..n"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "id": "",
            "type": "",
            "relationship": {
                "id": "3006:34",
                "fkey_logical_column_id": "2006:42",
                "pkey_logical_column_id": "2006:70",
                "fkey_column_id": "3003:10",
                "fkey_column_name": "\"localhost:1521/orcl\"..\"OT\".\"ORDER_ITEMS\".\"PRODUCT_ID\"",
                "pkey_column_id": "3003:29",
                "pkey_column_name": "\"localhost:1521/orcl\"..\"OT\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"PRODUCT_ID\"",
                "fkey_table_id": "3001:7",
                "pkey_table_id": "3001:25",
                "pkey_physical_table_name": "",
                "pkey_business_table_name": "",
                "type": "",
                "fkey_business_column_name": "\"ofline_online_test\".\"ORDER_ITEMS\".\"PRODUCT_ID\"",
                "pkey_business_column_name": "\"ofline_online_test\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"PRODUCT_ID\"",
                "from_type": "0..1",
                "to_type": "n..n"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "id": "",
            "type": "",
            "relationship": {
                "id": "3006:35",
                "fkey_logical_column_id": "2006:67",
                "pkey_logical_column_id": "2006:61",
                "fkey_column_id": "3003:26",
                "fkey_column_name": "\"localhost:1521/orcl\"..\"OT\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"CATEGORY_ID\"",
                "pkey_column_id": "3003:22",
                "pkey_column_name": "\"localhost:1521/orcl\"..\"OT\".\"PRODUCT_CATEGORIES\".\"CATEGORY_ID\"",
                "fkey_table_id": "3001:25",
                "pkey_table_id": "3001:21",
                "pkey_physical_table_name": "",
                "pkey_business_table_name": "",
                "type": "",
                "fkey_business_column_name": "\"ofline_online_test\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"CATEGORY_ID\"",
                "pkey_business_column_name": "\"ofline_online_test\".\"PRODUCT_CATEGORIES\".\"CATEGORY_ID\"",
                "from_type": "0..1",
                "to_type": "n..n"
            }
        }
    ]
}

process(item)
print(item)
```

Output:

```
{
    "relationship": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "id": "",
            "type": "",
            "relationship": {
                "id": "3006:34",
                "fkey_logical_column_id": "2006:42",
                "pkey_logical_column_id": "2006:70",
                "fkey_column_id": "3003:10",
                "fkey_column_name": '"localhost:1521/orcl".."OT"."ORDER_ITEMS"."PRODUCT_ID"',
                "pkey_column_id": "3003:29",
                "pkey_column_name": '"localhost:1521/orcl".."OT"."PRODUCTS"."PRODUCT_ID"',
                "fkey_table_id": "3001:7",
                "pkey_table_id": "3001:25",
                "pkey_physical_table_name": "",
                "pkey_business_table_name": "",
                "type": "",
                "fkey_business_column_name": '"ofline_online_test"."ORDER_ITEMS"."PRODUCT_ID"',
                "pkey_business_column_name": '"ofline_online_test"."PRODUCTS"."PRODUCT_ID"',
                "from_type": "0..1",
                "to_type": "n..n",
            },
        },
        {
            "name": "",
            "id": "",
            "type": "",
            "relationship": {
                "id": "3006:35",
                "fkey_logical_column_id": "2006:67",
                "pkey_logical_column_id": "2006:61",
                "fkey_column_id": "3003:26",
                "fkey_column_name": '"localhost:1521/orcl".."OT"."PRODUCTS"."CATEGORY_ID"',
                "pkey_column_id": "3003:22",
                "pkey_column_name": '"localhost:1521/orcl".."OT"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_ID"',
                "fkey_table_id": "3001:25",
                "pkey_table_id": "3001:21",
                "pkey_physical_table_name": "",
                "pkey_business_table_name": "",
                "type": "",
                "fkey_business_column_name": '"ofline_online_test"."PRODUCTS"."CATEGORY_ID"',
                "pkey_business_column_name": '"ofline_online_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_ID"',
                "from_type": "0..1",
                "to_type": "n..n",
            },
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
id_input = '3001:14'
item["relationship"] = [
    i for i in item["relationship"] if i["relationship"]["pkey_table_id"] != id_input
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer with a little modification to your own code:

```
id_input = "3001:14"
item['relationship'] = list(filter(lambda i: i['relationship']['pkey_table_id'] != id_input, item['relationship']))
```

1. Make sure that `id_input` is a valid string!
2. You must pass item['relationship'] to the filter function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
val_to_remove = '3001:25'
for i in item['relationship']:
    if i['relationship']['pkey_table_id'] == val_to_remove :         
        item['relationship'].remove(i)
```